# find out libjpeg version at runtime (or other ways to prevent aborts)?

Tags: c, libjpeg

my application uses libjpeg to read/write JPEG-images. everything worked fine

recently my app started to crash when trying to write JPEG images with an error "Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62" when calling jpeg_create_compress() (so the crash seems to be an intentional abort on the libjpeg side rather than a segfault)

a bit of investigation showed that indeed my application was compiled against libjpeg-62 headers (that were installed in /usr/local/include) and was then using the dylibs from libjpeg-80 (installed in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/).

removing the libjpeg-62 headers and compiling using the libjpeg-80 headers solved the problem.

however, i would appreciate a solution that would allow me to prevent such crashes, even if some end-user has a different library version installed than my app was compiled against.

1) it would be great if i could somehow convince libjpeg to not abort even on fatal errors;
e.g. something like:

```
jpeg_abort_on_error(0);
```

2) or have a non-aborting check whether the correct library is installed:

```
if(!jpeg_check_libraryversion()) return;
```

3) if that's not doable out of the box, i'm fine with manually checking the compile-time API-version (JPEG_LIB_VERSION) against a compat-version detected at runtime.

unfortunately i have not been able to find anything in the API that would allow me to use either of those methods.

am i just blind or do i need a something completely different?

Comment: i tagged this as "debian" as the problem appears on a debian-based system; debian transitioned from libjpeg62 to libjpeg8 a while ago)

Comment: Statically link against the jpeg lib then.

Comment: This is no easy question!  What you want to do is not necessarily impossible, but it does tend to cut against the grain of the Debian system, doesn't it?  Good luck.

Comment: @thb: i think that tagging this as "debian" was probably wrong, so i removed it. a proper debian system (without interfering stuff in /usr/local) should indeed not have this problem; nevertheless, my app is cross platform and not bound to any distribution and i'm afraid the problem can appear on all target platforms - given that libjpeg-62 and libjpeg-80 **appear** to be both API and ABI compatible (at least those subsets that i use), but really are not

Comment: You are asking for *another* way to crash your program.  Even though the original check is already perfectly capable of detecting and reporting the mismatch.

Comment: @HansPassant so how do i prevent the original check in the library from aborting my program? i think it's poor error-handling if a library detects a problem and then quits the calling application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting up an error-handler for error_exit prevents the application from crashing.

(my problem was that i had this done for the load-functionality, but *not* for the save-functionality, hence it exited when there were problems during saving).
something like the following did the trick:

```
struct my_error_mgr {
  struct jpeg_error_mgr pub;    // "public" fields
  jmp_buf setjmp_buffer;    // for return to caller
};
typedef struct my_error_mgr * my_error_ptr;

METHODDEF(void) my_error_exit (j_common_ptr cinfo) {
 my_error_ptr myerr = reinterpret_cast<my_error_ptr> (cinfo->err);
 /* Return control to the setjmp point */
 longjmp(myerr->setjmp_buffer, 1);
}

/* ... */

void jpeg_save(const char*filename, struct image*img) {
  /* ... */
  /* We set up the normal JPEG error routines, then override error_exit */
  my_error_mgr jerr;
  cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr.pub);
  jerr.pub.error_exit = my_error_exit;

  /* Establish the setjmp return context for my_error_exit to use. */
  if ( setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer) ) {
    /* If we get here, the JPEG code has signaled an error.
     * We need to clean up the JPEG object, close the input file, and return. */
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);
    if(outfile)fclose(outfile);
    return(false);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "jpeglib.h"
#include <iostream>

// JPEG error handler
void JPEGVersionError(j_common_ptr cinfo)
   {
   int jpeg_version = cinfo->err->msg_parm.i[0];
   std::cout << "JPEG version: " << jpeg_version << std::endl;
   }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {

    // Need to construct a decompress struct and give it an error handler
    // by passing an invalid version number we always trigger an error 
    // the error returns the linked version number as the first integer parameter
    jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    jpeg_error_mgr error_mgr;
    error_mgr.error_exit = &JPEGVersionError;
    cinfo.err = &error_mgr;
    jpeg_CreateDecompress(&cinfo, -1 /*version*/, sizeof(cinfo)); // Pass -1 to always force an error

   }
```